# Rhythmbox crashes during startup

Tags: startup, rhythmbox, plugins

I enabled Replay Gain in Rhythmbox and the program closed and now I cannot open the program at all. If I run it from terminal I am met with:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
**
ERROR:/build/buildd/pygobject-3.0.0/gi/_gobject/pygobject.c:929:pygobject_new_full: assertion failed: (tp != NULL)
Aborted
```

If I uninstall the "plugins for rhythmbox music player" package, Rhythmbox opens, obviously missing all of the plugins.

I am assuming there's a config file or folder somewhere enabling all of the plugins I selected when I re-install the "plugins for rhythmbox music player" package because when I re-install the package, the issue occurs again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok This was a tricky one. It turns out there was no issue with the Replay Gain plugin but rather the Magnatune plugin. What I needed to do was disable it being loaded when opening Rhythmbox by doing this:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `dconf-editor`
2. Navigating to **org > gnome > rhythmbox > plugins**
3. Removed the magnatune entry from *active-plugins*
4. (Don't know if this helped) navigated further within the Rhythmbox plugins menu to **magnatune > source** and deselected *show-browser*

Comment: Please file a bug report as well on Launchpad.net?

Answer (score 1):

Run this in terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/magnatune/
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/magnatune/
```

And try to launch Rhythmbox again!